# How to stop NetworkManager?

Tags: networking, network-manager

Is there any way to stop NetworkManager applet and switch to manual configuration of /etc/network/interfaces?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you manually configure an interface in /etc/network/interfaces, NetworkManager will not manage it. For example, add the following to interfaces file:

```
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Then restart NM service (`sudo service network-manager restart`), now NM appplet will say that device is not managed.

Comment: But NetworkManager will feel perfectly free to rewrite the interfaces file, throwing away all your additions, so be sure and have a backup handy.

Comment: @ubfan1 Not, really. NetworkManager doesn't write config to the interfaces file. I added `iface eth0 inet dhcp` to my interfaces and after `sudo service network-manager restart` NM says the wired network interface is unmanaged and I'm not allowed to interact with it via NM.

Comment: On 13.10 I get `service network-manager restart
stop: Unbekannter Auftrag: network-manager`

Comment: This worked for me. I just commented out the line. Thank you, Eric!

Answer (score 8):

to stop network manager

```
sudo /etc/init.d/network-manager stop
```

To stop it from managing `eth0` on next reboot, edit `/etc/network/interfaces` like so, changing the addresses to suit your needs

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 10.0.1.69
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 10.0.1.1
    dns-search example.com
    dns-nameservers 10.0.1.8 10.0.1.9
```

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo /etc/init.d/network-manager stop
```

This is the command to stop network-manager applet in both Gnome3 and Unity. hope that helps

Comment: what happens after a reboot

Comment: Upon reboot, NM will start again. If you really want it to go away forever, remove it and reboot.

Comment: This is not working anymore on 13.10

Comment: For 13.10+: sudo service network-manager stop